# How to add an exit message on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile

The problem is with the "pagehide" event, it doesn't work properly for iOS. It shows the confirmation message but if the user clicks "cancel" h/she doesn't stay on the page.
I tried this variant:

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(event) {
    // some code
    return confirm("Help us improve! Take a 10s survey");
});
```

I also tried to prevent the page from loading (it doesn't work at all) and to track the history change but it didn't give any results. Maybe I did something wrong. Please help! :)

Here's the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tcqkimIt95Z0FSeDUzWUxKZ1E/view) how it works for Android. It should be the same for iOS.

P.S.:

1. Also it would be great to have an exit message on closing or switching the tab and closing browser. I'm not sure that it's even possible.
2. The main task is to add custom exit message. But I didn't find opportunity to add such message without "confirmation message".